# Induction: $\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt n}}} < 3$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm trying to prove that

$$
\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots\sqrt{n}}}} < 3
$$

for any $n$ and have decided to use strong induction and instead just show that

$$
\sqrt{k\sqrt{(k + 1)\cdots\sqrt{n}}} < k + 1
$$

for any choice of $k$. Does anyone have an idea on where to proceed from here?

Comment: Multiply by $k-1$ and evaluate the square root at both sides...

Answer (score 2):

You might consider this.
$$ \sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt n}}} = 2^{1/2}\cdot 3^{1/4} \cdots n^{1/2^n}
=\exp\left\{\sum_{k=2}^n {\log(k)\over 2^{k-1}}
\right\}$$
Can you bound the sum inside.  It is convergent?

Answer (score 1):

Fix $n$. We prove by (downward) induction on $k$ ($k \le n$) that:

$$\sqrt{k\sqrt{(k+1)\cdots\sqrt n}} < k+1$$

For $k=n$ it is evident. Given $\sqrt{(k+1)\cdots \sqrt n}<k+2$, note that:

$$\frac12(k +(k+2)) = k+1 \ge \sqrt{k(k+2)}$$

by the AM-GM inequality. Use the induction hypothesis to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

For every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, let $x_{k,n}=\sqrt{k\sqrt{(k + 1)\cdots\sqrt{n}}}$. Then $x_{k,n}^2=kx_{k+1,n}$ hence if $x_{k+1,n}\lt k+2$ then $x_{k,n}^2\lt k(k+2)=(k+1)^2-1\lt(k+1)^2$ hence $x_{k,n}\lt k+1$. The downward recursion on $k$ such that $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, for any fixed value of $n\geqslant1$, is complete once one notes that $x_{n,n}=\sqrt{n}\lt n+1$ because $(n+1)^2-n=n^2+n+1\geqslant3\gt0$.